# PostgreSQL source code - offsetof() + sizeof() to get size of a stuct?

Tags: c, postgresql, sizeof, offsetof

I was scanning the source code of pgSQL and found an interesting macro.

```c
#define SizeOfXLogRecord    (offsetof(XLogRecord, xl_crc) + sizeof(pg_crc32c))
```

The definition of the `XLogRecord` is

```c
typedef struct XLogRecord
{
    uint32      xl_tot_len;     /* total len of entire record */
    TransactionId xl_xid;       /* xact id */
    XLogRecPtr  xl_prev;        /* ptr to previous record in log */
    uint8       xl_info;        /* flag bits, see below */
    RmgrId      xl_rmid;        /* resource manager for this record */
    /* 2 bytes of padding here, initialize to zero */
    pg_crc32c   xl_crc;         /* CRC for this record */

    /* XLogRecordBlockHeaders and XLogRecordDataHeader follow, no padding */

} XLogRecord;
```

I am confused about why the micro uses the sum of `offsetof` of the last member and the `sizeof` the last member to define the size of the stuct? Would there be any difference if I directly use `sizeof` of the struct?

By the way, what is the size of the struct `XLogRecord`? I think it's 24 bytes because of memory alignment. <s>But I saw from [here](http://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql09.html) that the size is 32 bytes ([pciture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftOBJ.png)). Can someone also explain this?</s>
**Update**: the size of `XLogRecord` varies from versions. In the latest version this size is exactly 24 bytes.

Any help or information will be appreciated.

The code is an excerpt from https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/4035cd5d4eee4dae797bfc77ab07f8dcd8781b41/src/include/access/xlogrecord.h

Comment: I think the idea is that the ```XLogRecord``` struct overlays a block of memory where additional data follows the struct (the ```XLogRecordBlockHeaders``` mentioned in the struct comment). ```sizeof(XlogRecord)``` might give a misleading offset to ```XLogRecordBlockHeaders``` if the compiler would otherwise add padding after ```xl_crc```. ```offsetof + sizeof``` won't have that problem.

Comment: From version 9.5 or later, the size of `XLogRecord` has been changed to 24 bytes. Have updated the post. Thanks for @sj95126 's explanation. To my understanding, the complier won't add padding after the `XLogRecord`. Because the size of the struct is 24 bytes and the largest member is 8 bytes (`TransactionId`). I think it is already aligned. Also according to @sj95126, if we do so to fix the padding which is added by the complier, does it mean we intentionally omit the memory alignment mechanism? Sacrifice performance to decrease the memory?